# How to add 2D elements in WEBGL mode?

Tags: p5.js

I am making a 3D sandbox game using p5.js and would like to add a menu using 2D elements how would I do this?

Comment: Please show your code so far and your attempts at adding 2d elements. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

With the P5.js library you can have multiple "backgrounds" layered on top of each other. With the `createGraphics` function you can create a non-WEBGL canvas on top of the 3D canvas I assume you have already created. The full usage is here: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics

Side note: I don't recommend creating a 3D sandbox with pure P5.js (even with more external libraries), It's extremely hard to program a camera and rendering system that's reliable and efficient. Using Unity, Unreal Engine or something similar is HIGHLY recommended (I speak from many hours of wasted time and experience with this).